# TypeError : "setHover" is not a function React JS

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys i'm following a tutorial for React and i did pretty much the same things but i keep getting this message error here is the code :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
...
...

const HeroSection = () => {
    const {hover, setHover} = useState(false);

    const onHover = () => {
        setHover(!hover)
    }

    ...
    ...
                <HeroBtnWrapper>
                    <Button to="signup" onMouseEnter={onHover} onMouseLeave={onHover} primary="true" dark="true">
                        Get Started {hover ? <ArrowForward/> : <ArrowRight/>}
                    </Button>
                </HeroBtnWrapper>
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: `{hover, setHover}` -> `[hover, setHover]`

Comment: I think u messed up `{hover, setHover}` here , its supposed to be `[hover,setHover]`.

Comment: yeah I just saw that hahaha i yelled....thank you guys <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use square brackets on your state declaration.

```
const [hover, setHover] = useState(false);
```